# Prove or disprove $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty l(cI_n ) = c\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n ) $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

For an interval $I_n$ in the set of real numbers, say $I_n= (x_n, y_n)$, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is the following equality true for any $c>0$?

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty l(cI_n ) = c\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n )  $$

where $l(I_n)$ is the length of the interval $I_n$ and $l(cI_n)$ the length of the interval $cI_n$.

What is an idea in mathematics that justifies this, or what is its counterexample?

Attempt: I believe that the equality holds. I have tried with a small value of $n$ and also, with an infinite $I_n$. They are both true. But is it true in general? Also, I am not sure if a very small positive number $c$ multiplied to $\infty$ still results in $\infty$. So, is there also a restriction of $c$ such that the equality holds?

Comment: if the series converge, then you can prove using: 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |\sum_{i=1}^{n} l(cI_n) - \sum_{i=1}^{n} cl(I_n)| = 0$$

Comment: do we have a name for this limit?

Comment: $|cx_n-cy_n|=c|x_n-y_n|$, therefore $l(cI_n )=cl(I_n )$

Comment: why is it true that your proof is correct after we incorporate the infinite sum?

Comment: Whether converges or not, $\sum_{n=1}^N ca_n = c\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ doesn't converge, you can't really say your original equation either. Instead, we can still say what @Porufes wrote above.